# Implementing dry run in a bash script

Tags: bash, function, shell, scripting, eval

I'm looking for an elegant way to implement a dry run in one of my bash scripts.
I found multiple ways to do that, but none of them fits to my needs.

One of them consists in writing a dry-run function like suggested here : https://gist.github.com/pablochacin/32442fbbdb99165d6f7c

But some commands I want to execute include pipes, and this method is no pipe-compatible.
For example, I want to execute this in dry run :

```
tar cf - drytestfile | 7z a -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mmt=$nbCores -si drytestfile.tar.7z | tee -a /tmp/testlog
```

Using the method above, I will then have this in my script, where $DRYRUN contains the name of the function doing an echo of all parameters :

```
$DRYRUN tar cf - drytestfile | 7z a -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mmt=$nbCores -si drytestfile.tar.7z | tee -a /tmp/testlog
```

This, of course, will run the function on the first part of the command (meaning the tar), and feed 7z with the result of this function.
Not really what I'm looking for.

Maybe there is something to do with the eval command instead, but I stil can't figure out how to implement that...
Any idea ?

Comment: `$DRYRUN tar cf - drytestfile | $DRYRUN 7z a -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mmt=$nbCores -si drytestfile.tar.7z | $DRYRUN tee -a /tmp/testlog` if you want to see the output of the command run before the pipe use `$PIPESTATUS` in the dryrun function

Comment: `dryrun tar | dryrun 7z | dryrun tee` -- but what's the point/value/purpose?

Comment: ...if you just want to almost-but-not run commands, a DEBUG trap could do that with less-invasive modifications to the rest of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are piping you need to have the "$DRYRUN" for all the commands in the line.  If you just add $DRYRUN in front of all the commands, then it will work, but you will only see the output from the last command.  If you want to show all commands, one way would be to change the dryrun function i.e.(**Edited per Charles Duffy comments**):

```
dryrun() {
    if [[ ! -t 0 ]]
    then
        cat
    fi
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"; echo "DRYRUN: Not executing $cmd_str" >&2
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$DRYRUN tar cf - drytestfile | \
$DRYRUN 7z a -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mmt=$nbCores -si drytestfile.tar.7z | \
$DRYRUN tee -a /tmp/testlog
```

For example:

```
dryrun echo "hello" | \
dryrun echo "world" | \
dryrun echo "foo" | \
dryrun echo "bar"
```

Will produce:

```
DRYRUN: Not executing command echo hello
DRYRUN: Not executing command echo world
DRYRUN: Not executing command echo foo
DRYRUN: Not executing command echo bar
```

Comment: Well, I tested it, it works like a charm ! Thank you very much ! :)
Just sad the display is going backwards, but I can deal with it, the most important for me is getting the information I need !!

Again thank you very much :)

Comment: I edited the answer so it is not displayed 'backwards', can you please mark it as a verified answer, Thanks.

Comment: `printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"; echo "DRYRUN: Not executing $cmd_str" >&2` is going to provide a more accurate description of your command. Putting `"$@"` in the string is going to result in inaccurate output

Comment: To provide a concrete example, you can't tell the difference between `echo "hello world"` and `echo "hello" "world"`, even though if you're passing these as arguments to any other command the quoting and whitespace matters.

Comment: ...and `</dev/stdin` is completely redundant, no?

Comment: BTW, `function foo() {` is combining legacy ksh and POSIX sh function declaration syntax in a way that's compatible with neither. Pick one or the other, as described in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you.